# Unable to scroll with the mouse wheel in my flipview

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am developing a Windows 8 app with HTML5 and Javascript. 
I decided to use a `FlipView`. My template for this consists of several `div` which contains the HTML.

Everything works except for one thing, my `div` containing the HTML I added the option `overflow: scroll`, the scrollbar appears, but my problem is that I can not scroll that pressing the `ScrollBar`. Unable to retrieve mousewheel event.

What is the solution to successfully scroll (horizontal scroll) also with the mouse wheel? (No worries for browsing with your finger).

Comment: You should close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the event to wheel up mousewheel.